# Class variable (counter) not getting incremented - Python

Tags: oop, python-3.x

I have the following code:

```
class Account(object):

    counter=0

    def __init__(self, holder, number, balance,credit_line=1500): 
        self.Holder = holder 
        self.Number = number 
        self.Balance = balance
        self.CreditLine = credit_line

    def __del__(self):
        Account.counter -= 1

    def transfer(self, target, amount): 
        if(self.Balance - amount < -self.CreditLine):
            # coverage insufficient
            return False  
        else: 
            self.Balance -= amount 
            target.Balance += amount 
            return True

    def deposit(self, amount): 
        self.Balance = amount 

    def withdraw(self, amount): 
        if(self.Balance - amount < -self.CreditLine):
            # coverage insufficient
            return False  
        else: 
            self.Balance -= amount 
            return True 

    def balance(self): 
        return self.Balance

a1 = Account("abc", 2, 2325.21)

print(Account.counter)
```

The output shows 0. However, I guess it should show as 1 since one object as been initialized. Why is it showing 0, and how to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

`counter` is not increased when initializing the object.

Use:

```
def __init__(self, holder, number, balance,credit_line=1500): 
    ...
    Account.counter+=1
```

Also the destructor `__del__` will be called from garbe collection and you could not really predict when this happens. So it is not a destructor in the sense of C++. It's always better to call an explicit object method for this purpose.